# Like query string in codelgniter

Tags: codeigniter, search

My view page has the following fields

```
id,name,email,gender etc..
```

I have a search box , and i want to perform search in all the above fields

How to write the query string in CI way

**Controller**

```
public function search()
    {


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('search_term', 'Search_term', 'trim|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
             $keyword = $this->input->post('search_term');

             $sql.= "WHERE name like '{$keyword }'";
             $sql.= "OR email like '{$keyword }'"; 
             $sql.= "OR gender like '{$keyword }'";          

        }

        $query = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: You can look at database active records you can choose your version of user guide here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read  [CI Like](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)  like query

```
    $keyword = $this->input->post('search_term');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('name', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('email', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('gender', $keyword);
    $res = $this->db->get('users');
```

Comment: Totally agreed with solution. Only, please provide new hoster CI userguide link(s). 
[v2](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html), [v3](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html).